# How to securely store mosquitto.conf file?

Tags: docker, encryption, mqtt, mosquitto

I am using eclipse-mosquitto Docker image and the Docker file is:

```
FROM eclipse-mosquitto

ADD config /mosquitto/config
ADD data /mosquitto/data
ADD log /mosquitto/log
ADD p2.txt /mosquitto/config/
```

And I have mosquitto.conf file under config folder as a plain text as:

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
listener 1883
allow_anonymous false
password_file /mosquitto/config/p2.txt
```

But I don't want anyone to see and/or change the content of the .conf file. For example, if "**allow_anonymous**" field is changed to "**true**", client services will not need a password to listen the message broker. Is there a way to securely store the file or encrypt the content of the file?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: How do you envision someone gaining access? Generally you would only expose ports Mosquitto is listening on; if someone can modify the config file via those ports then we have major issues! Should an attacker gain sufficient access to change `mosquitto.conf` then they will also most likely be able to change other things (e.g. the Mosquitto executable) so encryption would be of limited benefit. If you are mounting `/mosquitto/config` then ensure the source is secured.

Comment: Ad @Brits said, if somebody has enough access to your system to rebuild your docker container after editing the file, they already have full access to your system and it is no longer your system.